# How to re-use angularjs directives in your own directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am doing an exercise of wrapping an existing ngDirective without using a an html template fragment. In the example, I am merely repurposing an `ng-show`. I realise there are problems with this (eg hard coding `item.viewing`) and you might ask why, but leave that aside for moment unless there is a better idiom. I can't see it doesn't work - I add the attribute and then compile it into scope. Is there a scope issue? I can't see that priority or transclusion are needed.

The code that works looks like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat='item in collection'>
  <li ng-show='item.viewing'>text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to replace the `li` with

```
<li viewing>text</li>
```

Here is the angularjs directive code:

```
app.directive('viewing', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      tAttrs.$set('ngShow', 'item.viewing');
      return function(scope, elem, attr){
        $compile(scope, elem, attr);
       };
     }
   };
});
```

Here's a working version: http://plnkr.co/PjusCDkgt7PuXKtZowbH

Apologies for stupidity in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple things kept this from working:

1. `$compile` takes an some HTML and returns a linking function, which is called with a `scope` to link the compiled DOM to the given scope.
2. You need to remove the `viewing` attribute from the DOM, else when you re-compile the element again with `$compile` you launch into an infinite loop.

Here's the [working directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/0cB3GO5SMPPOL6s0UUFf?p=preview):

```
app.directive('viewing', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
      tAttrs.$set('ngShow', 'item.viewing');
      tElem.removeAttr('viewing');
      return function(scope, elem, attr){
        $compile(elem)(scope);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Good point about removing the viewing. I also use `tAttrs.$set('viewing')`. Looking at the source for angular suggests that these are equivalent. Agreed?

Comment: I recommend replacing `tElem.removeAttr('viewing');` with `tElem.removeAttr(tAttrs.$attr['viewing']);` to prevent normalization issues, in case you're using some other directive name (e.g. `ng-viewing`). Documentation: http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes